# Как правильно писать окончание?

Tags: лексика

"Фотографы 1900-1903 года" или "фотографы 1900-1903 годов"?

Comment: Народ, не забываем одобрять вопросы!!!

Answer (score 1):

Верно "Фотографы 1900—1903 годов".

Answer (score 0):

Тире между датами подразумевает, что речь идёт о нескольких годах, поэтому "годов".

Answer (score 0):

Ответы правильные, только хотелось бы уточнить, что нельзя сказать *"фотографы тысяча девятисот**ых** — тысяча девятьсот треть**их** годов* — есть опасение, что кто-то так может прочитать, — а надо: *тысяча девятисотого — тысяча девятьсот третьего годов.*